# hashtable performance in glibc

Tags: c, glibc

I am writing some programs in C and the performance is important, so I am faced by following situation. I have a long linked list(millions), each node of the linked list is another struct, this can be a linkedlist or hashtable, the operations I will do on each node include following:

```
iterate all the elements in the linkedlist/hashtable, 
check the existence of an element in the linkedlist/hashtable ,
```

normally we should use hashtable for it, but in my situation, there will be only 2~5 elements in total, is that possible that using hashtable will bring large overhead (both time and space) and makes it less attractive?

I am using glibc.

Comment: Implement it both ways, and benchmark it. It's unlikely anyone can estimate the difference accurately.

Comment: For 2-5 elements I'd probably just use an array, not list or hash.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the proposal, actually that's a good idea, I thought about it but gave up, because occasionally there will be node with a little bit more than that, but won't be too much.

Comment: I am trying to do a benchmark right away if nobody has had this situation.

Comment: Many people have had similar situations. But if every microsecond is critical, they won't be similar enough to be the right answer for you.

Comment: E.g. your data is 2-5 elements, they might be 5-10, and that's different enough that it's useless to you.

Comment: Just did some simple benchmark, but it didn't help, I guess I need complicated data to do the benchmark, but I rethink about using array, you are right, it might be better, for the case that are larger than 5 elements, I just need to resize the array. @Barmar